# PHP - Generating Dynamic XML with Mysql Database values as xml attribute value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to generate an XML file on button click which fetches values from mysql database and assign it to XML line attributes. Basically generating an XML file which will be imported into MSSQL Server DB.

Unable to add child element from inside a `foreach` PHP loop. Code is below

```
$querytwo = $this->db->query("Select * from ProjectActivtyperDay where idEmployeeWeeklyTimesheetDetails=".$IdEmpTsDetails);
foreach ($querytwo->result() as $rowtwo)
            {
                $line = xml_add_child($prtransaction,'taPATimeSheetLineInsert','');}
```

However, I can see line element is added when I use `xml_print` (I have defined this function) when I run the code on Internet Explorer but it does not work on google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
foreach ($query as $parent => $child) {  
echo $child;       

foreach ($child as $parent2 => $child2){  
echo $child2;  

foreach ($child2 as $parent3 => $child3){  
echo $child3;
}
}
}
```

Comment: I was creating an XML and it is creating an headerInsert but not creating a Lineinsert  why?